# No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread

Tags: spring, spring-jpa

В приложении на Spring JPA возникает исключение `No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call` при сохранении entity. Что может быть не так в довольно стандартном коде?

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("aoizora")

```
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb =
                new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("test-jpa-unit");
        return emfb;
    }
}


@Repository
@Transactional
public class JpaGreetingRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addGreeting(Greeting greeting) {
        em.persist(greeting);
    }

    public Greeting findGreeting(Long id) {
        return em.find(Greeting.class, id);
    }

    public void saveGreeting(Greeting greeting) {
        em.merge(greeting);
    }
}


@Service
@Transactional
public class GreetingService {

    @Autowired
    private JpaGreetingRepository repository;

    public void save(Greeting greeting) {
        repository.addGreeting(greeting);
    }
}


@Entity
public class Greeting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String greeting;
    @Column
    private String target;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public String getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(String target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        GreetingService service = ctx.getBean(GreetingService.class);

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.setGreeting("Hello");
        greeting.setTarget("World");

        service.save(greeting);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исключение падает т.к. нет транзакции в которой энтити менеджеру надо выполняться. Похоже что аннотация `@Transactional` не проинициализировалась как надо. 
Есть вариант либо починить аннотацию указав `@EnableTransactionManagement` в конфигурации либо управлять транзакциями вручную через `EntityManager`

Comment: Если указать @EnableTransactionManagement, возникает исключение No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available. А вызовы типа em.getTransaction().begin() запрещены спрингом.